# Service on local computer started then stopped error

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services, event-log, custom-eventlog

I have a windows service. It was working fine until I added code for it to begin logging.  Now when I try to start the service I receive the following error:

> The GBBService service on local computer started then stopped. Some
>   services stopped automatically if they have no work to do, for
>   example, the performance logs and alert service

Here is the code for my service:
- From inside project installer

```
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    string eventSource = "GBBServiceLog";

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        EventLogInstaller installer = FindInstaller(this.Installers);
        if (installer != null)
        {
            installer.Source = eventSource;
            installer.Log = "My GBBServiceLog";
        }
    }

    private EventLogInstaller FindInstaller(InstallerCollection installers)
    {
        foreach (Installer installer in installers)
        {
            if (installer is EventLogInstaller)
            {
                return (EventLogInstaller)installer;
            }
            EventLogInstaller eventLogInstaller = FindInstaller(installer.Installers);
            if (eventLogInstaller != null)
                return eventLogInstaller;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected override void OnCommitted(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.OnCommitted(savedState);
        // Start the service after installation
        using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
        {
            sc.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

From within my service:

```
public GBBService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        EventLog.Source = eventSource;
        EventLog.Log = "My GBB Service Log";

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("GBBService Service Started");
    }
```

Did I do something wrong in my code?

Comment: is it becaue you created the eventlog `My GBBServiceLog` in the installer and in the Service you are tring to write to `My GBB Service Log`

Comment: so it needs to be the same in both places? this is the url I referenced when working on it: http://blog.embrodesign.com/2012/05/event-log-from-windows-service/ wasn't sure whether the log names were to be the same or different

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the same name, `My GBB Service Log` does not exist so you need to create it in the service or use the one you created in the Installer.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 that was it please add it as an answer so I can close this!

Comment: no problems :), glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you are trying to write to a `EventLog` that does not exist.

In the `ServiceInstaller` you create the `EventLog` `My GBBServiceLog`

```
if (installer != null)
{
    installer.Source = eventSource;
    installer.Log = "My GBBServiceLog";
}
```

But in the `Service` you try to write to `My GBB Service Log`

```
public GBBService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    EventLog.Source = eventSource;
    EventLog.Log = "My GBB Service Log"; <--------------
}
```

I think it should be:

```
public GBBService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    EventLog.Source = eventSource;
    EventLog.Log = "My GBBServiceLog";
}
```